# Create a Regex to match a sequence of characters in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regex to match a sequence of characters in Java.

I have a phone `351967899766`

I have several area_Codes like: `123`,`456`,`351`

and I am looping between the area_codes and comparing with the phone and when I have a match(in a sequence of characters like 351) it send a message and stops looking for matches.

Do you have any ideia how to do this regex?

Comment: I think the reason this was commented on negatively when I saw it before is that this doesn't seem like the best use of regular expressions.

Comment: Can you tell me another alternative to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Is that the answer you are looking for? iterate the area codes and find if a phone number is started with the iterated area code.

```
    final String phone = "351967899766";
    for (String areaCode : Arrays.asList("123", "456", "351")) {
        if (phone.startsWith(areaCode)) {
            System.out.println("match");
            break;
        }
    }
```